# How to restrict UITextField to be only one of the elements of array

Tags: ios, swift

I have one text field which is a type of [SearchTextField](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SearchTextField) (from cocoapods). Basically I can set an array of strings and assign this array to the suggestion list for that text field. But the thing is that user can type whatever he/she wants to that text field and not to choose from the suggestion list which appears and updates dynamically while typing. But I want them to write only one element of that suggestion array. For ex if he types sth else some alert pops up. Could not find answer for this anywhere. Thanks in advance

P.s: My first question here)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you can achieve this. Assuming that your array isn't extremely large, what I would do is after the user fills out the TextField or moves onto another element in the form (clicks another TextField) check if the entry they entered in the TextField matches any of the strings in your array.

For example:

```
var yourTextField : UITextField!
let arrayElements = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]

if !arrayElements.contains(yourTextField.text!) { // if what they entered isn't in the suggested array
    // tell them to select an item from the suggested list
}
```

You can do something along the lines of that. You can pop up an error through a label for example, or give them a UIAlertController - really anyway you want to inform them to select something from the suggested list.

Comment: If I'm not wrong that should be possible inside of `yourTextField.itemSelectionHandler = { /*...*/ }`

Comment: How can I do that if user entered text which is not in array some erro-typed alert pops up?